# What is the correct way to simplify this derivative? (Derivative divided by another derivative.)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I am trying to simply some terms involving derivatives for a project I'm working on.

Here's a basic rule I believe to be true for dividing derivatives:

$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Therefore we can simply the following as:

$$\frac{(\frac{y_x}{||r_x||})_x}{y_{xx}} =\frac{\frac{y_x}{||r_x||}}{y_{x}}=\frac{1}{||r_x||}$$

I think this is correct.

But I am having trouble simplifying a similar equation in a way that performs as expected:

$$\frac{(\frac{1+y_x}{||r_x||})_x}{y_{xx}} = \frac{(\frac{y_x+1}{||r_x||})_x}{(y_x+1)_x} =\frac{(\frac{y_x+1}{||r_x||})}{(y_x+1)} = \frac{1}{||r_x||}$$

I thought it was reasonable to say $y_{xx} = (y_x+1)_x$ because the added constant 1 will be removed by the second derivative.

Is this correct? Is it then true:

$$\frac{(\frac{y_x}{||r_x||})_x}{y_{xx}} = \frac{(\frac{1+y_x}{||r_x||})_x}{y_{xx}}$$

I feel like this is not possible and it's causing problems. If what I did was wrong, why was it wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are avoiding applying the quotient rule...

The relation you are (actually) using is the chain rule,
$$  \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} \cdot \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} t}  \text{.}  $$

So, from your first example, we should expect
$\displaystyle   \left(\frac{y_x}{||r_x||} \right)_x = \frac{1}{||r_x||} y_{xx}  \text{.}  $
Of course, we can just evaluate the left-hand side:
\begin{align*}  \left(\frac{y_x}{||r_x||} \right)_x &= \frac{||r_x|| y_{xx} - y_x ||r_x||_x}{||r_x||^2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{||r_x||} y_{xx} - \frac{y_x ||r_x||_x}{||r_x||^2}  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Therefore, a condition that your first example is correct is $\displaystyle y_x ||r_x||_x = 0$.

Your second example has a similar difficulty.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Looks like I totally butchered that using the wrong rule. I have no formal math training past high school which was a long time ago so I'm just learning as I go. So is this then correct for the first term: $(\frac{y_x}{||r_x||})_x = \frac{y_{xx}||r_x|| - y_{x}(||r_x||)_x }{||r_x||^2}$

 And for the second term: 
$(\frac{y_x+1}{||r_x||})_x = \frac{y_{xx}||r_x|| - (y_{x}+1)(||r_x||)_x }{||r_x||^2}$ If so that covers it for me! Thanks.

Comment: @mike : Those look right to me.